# Selenium IDE: Selenium script execution stops at the first missing link

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I use Selenium IDE to test some webpage content.
My problem is: I have a test case with several 'clickAndWait' instructions on different links. Some  links are missing on the webpage. My test case stops at the first missing link. I need my test case to be executed entirely even if a link is missing.
Example:

> open  |    myurl.com  | 
>   clickAndWait | mainLink | 
>   clickAndWait | **minorLink1** | 
>   verifyTextPresent | text1 | 
>   clickAndWait | mainLink | 
>   clickAndWait | minorLink2 | 
>   verifyTextPresent | text2 | 
>   clickAndWait | mainLink | 
>   clickAndWait | minorLink3 | 
>   verifyTextPresent | text3 |

The problem is, if **minorLink1** does not exist, the whole test case is stopped, but I need minorLink2 and minorLink3 to be tested. 
Does anyone can help me?
Thanks by advance,
Thomas.

Comment: Selenium IDE does not support branching - which is what you are talking about. There are extensions for SeIDE that will give you that, but your effort is better spent on learning a real programming language, as @AndrewGauthier suggested in his answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Within the IDE you will not be able to run this as one test if you want it to continue, as the IDE simply follows the instruction order and has to stop when an instruction breaks. You could separate these into separate tests within the IDE, or you could move the operation to one of the supported environments like Java or C#, where you could write logic to avoid a full stop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

In my example, if the following instruction failed

>verifyTextPresent | text1 |

the analyze still continue. This failure is not considered as an instruction break?

Comment: Its not because it is explicitly a check for existence. The idea is that if you are verifying something, then there is a chance that it will not be present, and so the IDE carries out the check in a manner so that it can continue onwards afterwards regardless of the result. A verification check is a more passive action, while the clickAndWait instructions are active in that they change the state of the WebDriver, which means that if the click action doesn't work the rest of the script is out of line with the desired case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use loops which I have found to be very effective with ever changing lists where data can start on page one but end up on any page.

Or you could use gotoif command which would look something like this:

```
<tr>
 <td>storeElementPresent</td>
 <td>${category_header_obj}</td>
 <td>present</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>gotoIf</td>
 <td>storedVars['present']==false</td>
 <td>exit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>verifyText</td>
 <td>${category_header_obj}</td>
 <td>Categories</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Label</td>
<td></td>
<td>exit</td>
</tr>
```